# How were beings like the Living Tribunal and the One-Above-All formed?

Tags: marvel, the-living-tribunal

Were beings like the Living Tribunal and the One-Above-All formed from the Infinity Gems?

Comment: Should be split into 2 different questions. The question about The living tribunal and one above all are entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

### Not by the Infinity Gems

The [One-Above-All](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/One-Above-All_(Multiverse)) is 'apparently responsible for the existence of all life in the Multiverse and possibly beyond'.

The [Infinity Gems](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Gems) 'are powerful artifacts that originate from a primordial universe inhabited by Celestials'.

Therefore the Infinity Gems are derivative of the Multiverse and so the One-Above-All was **not** formed by them.

### The Living Tribunal is the direct creation of the One-Above-All

The [Living Tribunal](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Tribunal_(Multiverse)) safeguards the Multiverse on behalf of the One-Above-All, from whom the Tribunal derives its authority. The One-Above-All is the creator of the Living Tribunal, as the linked page indicates.

### The One-Above-All was not 'formed', being the principal of all that is

The One-Above-All, being a kind of analogue for the ultimate God of religion, is likely without beginning or end and so cannot have been 'formed'. As the principal of all universes, the One-Above-All is the un-caused and un-created One.

Answer (score 2):

We know that nemesis is less powerful than TOAA because the full infinity gauntlet is nothing next to him. It would be probably impossible to create a being more powerful than yourself, Nemesis could not have created TOAA. He is meant to have created the entire multiverse, which I think includes her. As for him, I think he has no origin and always was and just decided to create the multiverse. As I understand it, he created all other cosmic beings to do their desired effects on the universe for him e.g Galactus was there to balance eternity with death.

Comment: *It would be probably impossible to create a being more powerful than yourself* Forgot Magneto's creation of the Alpha?

Answer (score 1):

[Nemesis](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Nemesis_(Cosmic_Being)_(Earth-93060)) was the single being in existence. She created the multiverse when she shattered herself, and split into the infinity gems, the six singularities mentioned by the collector. This is what sparked the multiverse into being.

So, answering the question, they did exist as a single being, not separate entities before the multiverses were sparked into creation.

Comment: _"most powerful being bar none, but then..."_ - you seem to have lost a part of the sentence there.

Comment: I'm _very_ skeptical that the movie universe is ever going to get so deep into the multiverse concept as to get to the OAA...

Comment: The movie universe is included in the Marvel Multiverse. They are all part of the same multiverse, and there are even comics in the movie universes. =)

Comment: @Gallifreyan, no, I meant, when the statement about the OAA being the most powerful being came about, Nemesis wasn't a being anymore, it had already split into the infinity gems. So, we never get to know if the OAA is more powerful than Nemesis, or just the most powerful, because Nemesis isn't here. I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: This seems to be an answer to part of the question that was removed.

Comment: Yeah... the question is still in the title. Basically if the multiverse comes from the infinity stones. I'll edit to link the 6 singularities to explain that they are the infinity stones and come from Nemesis.

Comment: I thought the infinity stones were specific to a given universe, not the multiverse. E.g. each universe has its own set of six infinity stones.

Comment: @KutuluMike depends whether Kevin Feige feels like doing a cameo

Answer (score 0):

The four cosmic entities created the Infinity Stones, as seen on the walls of Morag in *Guardians of the Galaxy*

[image: Relief sculpture showing 4 figures gathered around a set of coloured stones]

Death, Entropy, Eternity and Infinity are the ones who created the Infinity Stones. The Living Tribunal is responsible for keeping the balance between universes and each universe has its own set of Infinity Stones, so it would not make any sense that the Living Tribunal was responsible for this. The One-Above-All is more of a representation of existence than a fully interactive and emotional cosmic being. The Infinity Stones have no control when it comes to the multiverse, the Infinity Stones do not work outside their home universe, as stated in Loki (Series).

**One-Above-All creation**

One-Above-All was not created and was un-created and just a mere representation of the the sum of all life and existence, the One-Above-All was not created by anything. The living tribunal was created by the One-Above-All to manage the balance of the multiverse.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  While this answers the part of the question if the One Above All or the Living Tribunal were created by the Infinity Stones, it doesn't answer _how_ those entities were formed.  Can you answer the entire question?

Comment: Alright, ill research more.